# c to mips code in computer organisation and architecture

Tags: c, mips

```
int i ;

void set_array(int num){
  int array[10];
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    array[i]=compare(num,i){
  }
}

int compare(int a ,int b){
  if(sub(a,b)>=0)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

int sub(int a,int b){
  return a-b;
}
```

anybody know how to convert to mips code

Comment: Give us a starting point, this is clearly a homework question. What have you understood so far?

Comment: The usual way would be to use a compiler that targets MIPS.

Comment: Look for a cross compiler if you're lazy. If you're truly writing MIPS though, the purpose would be to avoid the rare but occasional inefficiency in the generated code.

Comment: It's obviously a homework problem guys, so no, a compiler would be the cheap, fast, and cheating way to go.  Stop suggesting he use a compiler.

Comment: How do you mean here?  Do you mean hand-compiling it as if you were the C compiler or do you mean writing an application from the ground up in MIPS assembly that replicates the above behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need a cheat sheet: [MIPS Instruction Reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html)

A good reference sheet is the most useful thing possible when writing assembly for any architecture.

Secondly, start breaking the program down on the high level.  You know the functions and their names, so start there.  Start by defining the functions and creating a very basic definition for each function so that it is actually callable.

Next, write the code that will pull the function parameters from their respective places for each function.  You are lucky here as each function just accepts a basic integer.  You will need to move any function parameters into `$a0` - `$a3` before calling the function.  You can then write the code that moves your return value into `$v0` or `$v1` before returning.  Make sure in each function you write, you save off the registers you are using onto the stack and then restore them before your `jal $ra`.  Now you should have some functions that are callable and return values, but don't really do anything.

Lastly, actually write the junk that your functions do.  Again, you are luck as you are only using `int`... so each number will match to one register and you will only need to offset by 4 bytes when referencing the stack... making things easier.  I'll give you a hint for `int sub(int a, int b)`... it'll look something like this:

```
sub  $t2, $t1, $t0
```

Haha, see?  It's not so hard to write assembly :D

Of course you will then have to move your result into `$v0' or`$v1` at the end of the function and jump back to the callee.

Anyways, hope that gets you started.

Comment: +1 for "a good reference sheet is the most useful thing possible when writing assembly for any architecture".  Unless you're dealing with some truly minimalist architecture, processor instructions and timings are typically too complicated to keep in memory unless you eat, drink and breathe them for extended periods of time.  (And even then maybe not.)

Comment: I just noticed how evil you are, Polaris878.  Stack?

Comment: @ttmrichter... fixed haha, I was really tired when I wrote that and it has been a while since I've wrote assembly :D  Should be all good now.